# ORM and mysql replication lag

Tags: mysql, hibernate, orm, doctrine, master-slave

We are moving to a master/multi-slave MySQL setup and I am concerned about how to tackle the issue of data integrity without changing the application code too much.

Our application uses an ORM (Doctrine PHP) and in theory we could extend it to simply send SELECT statements to one of the slaves or to the master and UPDATE/DELETE queries to the master.

where this would fail due to the nature of the ORM is:

1. Doing writes based on outdated data from a slave, e.g. read a record from the slave that has recently had its column Y changed on the master but not yet on the slave and then saving a change on column X together with the outdated data of column Y on the master, thus overwriting the prior change to column Y.
2. Doing reads from the slave right after a recent write on the master (scenario where a user just posted a form - say a forum comment - and reloads the page and does not see his comment)

I am thinking that we should build the logic on our application controllers that should let the data layer know whether there is tolerance for getting outdated data and when not (e.g. when there is an intention to write) and when not so that the data layer can connect to master or slave accordingly, however; it seems against good software engineering practices. E.g. controllers should be implementing business logic not having to deal with whether the data should come from a slave or a master.

I am sure this has been dealt with in the past. Maybe not with Doctrine PHP, but with Hibernate or other ORM solutions?

Are there any general good practices or recommendations one could share?